# Vega OpenSearch: JSON url from Apache server loading failed

Tags: json, apache2, visualization, opensearch, vega

Vega from OpenSearch  fails to load the url, the same issue occurs in online Vega editor. However, it is perfectly fine and rendered if I paste in Web browser.

```
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A basic table example with embedded data.",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,
  "autosize": "none"

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "url": "http://ip.address/data.json",
      "format": {
        "property": "hits.hits", // Navigate through your Elasticsearch result structure
        "type": "json"
      }
    }
  ],

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "cellHeight",
      "value": 30
    }
  ],
```

Please advise the causes and possible solutions